# How can I go from the American side to the Canadian side of Niagara Falls?

Tags: visas, usa, canada, borders, niagara-falls

My friends told me that Niagara Falls look better from Canada but my bus will stop at the American side. Can I walk over a bridge or take any public transportation to the other side?

Also, as a non-citizen, do I need Canadian visa for crossing border and going around the falls?

Comment: "As a non-citizen—" you're presumably a citizen of somewhere, yes? If you tell us what citizenship you do have, we can better help you figure out if you require a visa to visit Canada.

Answer (score 9):

It depends if you are USA citizens or not. But nevertheless, [this site](http://www.niagarafallslive.com/niagara_falls_travel_tips.htm) has some useful tips and further links that will provide you with all necessary information for both cases.

btw... this FAQ make me really laughing:

> Q: Are the Falls turned off at night ?
>
> A: No

Comment: That FAQ entry made me...roflcoptr.

Comment: I was at the falls yesterday and, yes, I could easily walk to the Canadian side, given that I had Canadian visa. Anyway, I think you should include this or at least copy and paste some FAQs from the site to your answer just in case the site is down (and to meet the standard of other StackExchange sites.)

Comment: That FAQ isn't as much of a joke as you'd think.  They've got the ability to divert the entire flow of the falls through hydroelectric power plants, and they *do* reduce the flow over the falls at night.

Answer (score 3):

As a German citizen I usually have a visa waiver for the US for 90 days. This allows for side trips to Canada and Mexico (which are counted in the 90 days).

So you can just walk over the bridge, spend some hours or days on the Canadian side and then walk back into the U.S.

Having said that, this may not apply to a Thai citizen.