# Crossing the US-Canadian border and back

Tags: usa, canada, borders, esta, niagara-falls

My wife and I, citizens of Italy, will be traveling to New England for sightseeing. We will arrive and leave at/from New York JFK and rent a car. Since we would like to see Niagara Falls, we will need to cross the US-Canadian border and come back on the next day or so.

Questions:

- Are we able to leave the US and come back on the next day with the same ESTA registration?

Comment: Your question #2 [is covered by this existing question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/16999/crossing-from-us-into-canada-as-a-european-tourist-with-a-rental-car?rq=1)

Comment: Note, to see the Niagra Falls, you do not technically need to cross the border. From the US side, you can go on boat rides which take you right up to the Falls.

Comment: The best views of the falls are on the Canadian side, but some good views are available on the US side too.

Answer (score 4):

As @Gagravarr indicated you've already asked the 2nd question so I won't answer that again.

According to [US Customs and Border Protection Website](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1126/kw/reapply%20for%20ESTA/related/1)

> Your ESTA authorization is generally valid for multiple trips over a period of two years (starting the date that you are approved) or until your passport expires, whichever comes first*. This means that as long as you received an ESTA authorization to travel, you do not have to reapply during the validity period. You may update your travel information; however this information is optional and is not required.

So leaving US for one day to Canada and then coming back is not an issue as long as other terms of the Visa Waiver Program are satisfied.

**NOTE** Please note that your time in Canada counts against your 90 day allowed in the country under the Visa Waiver Program.